# There is "utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position" when pypy import any module

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, pypy

There is error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 23: invalid continuation byte when import module file

When I try to install the numpy for pypy3-v5.10.1-win32 (numpy download from https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy/downloads/)
It gave me this error.
I tried to convert the encoding of `version.py` and `setup.py` into utf-8 (by notepad and notepad++), but it's still not working

```
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\pypy-numpy-4f9778cd49a4\setup.py", line 131, in get_version_info
from numpy.version import git_revision as GIT_REVISION

# THESE CODE FROM  SETUP.PY
from numpy.version import git_revision as GIT_REVISION

# THIS IS VERSION.PY

short_version = '1.10.0'
version = '1.10.0'
full_version = '1.10.0'
git_revision = 'Unknown'
release = True

if not release:
    version = full_version
```

I find that import any  module will cause such error I use `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` checked the my pypy's encoding it's "utf-8".
How to fix this strange problem ?

Comment: Without a full traheback we can't see what exactly is wrong. Does your local file name or the output from `git` contain non-ASCII characters?

Comment: It's happened in WindowsXPSP3 x86 chinese language OS  And the PYPY's version is pypy3-v5.10.1-win32(highest verison for XP) 。So  I have to gave up this OS

Answer (score 0):

Do not use https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy. Use regular numpy, as documented on the pypy downloads site http://pypy.org/download.html#installing-numpy.